# write sitecore powershell inside C# code

Tags: powershell-extensions

I'm working with Sitecore 9.2 , And I need to create a custom button inside custom ribbon when click on button open dialog so the content author can select date and then i will do my business function after that

- first i created the ribbon
- then i created the button
- i created the command class which will contain the powershell code and my business function

the problem that the powershell script didn't executed , i need to know how to write powershell inside C# class and why my code didn't executed

```
public override void Execute(CommandContext context){
using (ScriptSession scriptSession = ScriptSessionManager.NewSession("Default", true)){ 
var command = "$result = Read-Variable -Parameters ` @{ Name=\"from\"; Value=[System.DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-5); Title=\"Start Date\"; Tooltip=\"Date since when you want the report to run\"; Editor=\"date time\"}` -Description \"This Dialog shows less editors, it doesn't need tabs as there is less of the edited variables\" `" +
" -Title \"Initialise various variable types (without tabs)\" -Width 500 -Height 480 -OkButtonName \"Proceed\" -CancelButtonName \"Abort\"  ";
List<object> results;
results = scriptSession.ExecuteScriptPart(command, false);
}
}
```

i found this error in the SPE log

> Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
> Message: Non interactive session cannot perform an interactive operation requested by the 'Read-Variable' command.

Comment: you can add a button to the ribbon without C# code. wouldn't it be enough for you? https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/modules/integration-points/content-editor

Comment: Definitely overdoing things here. There are integration points that allow you to tap into the various features of the Content Editor with only items and PowerShell.

Comment: Seems kind of counter-intuitive to go the effort of creating a button in C# and then not just writing the code in C#....

Comment: Thank you @TamásTárnok i will try this option, if it's worked it enough for sure

Comment: thank you @MichaelWest i will try powershell integration

Answer (score 0):

As per suggestion from @Tamás Tárnok and @Michael West ,it's easy way to create ribbon button using Powershell without any C# code

this Document is helpful
[powershell integration Points](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/modules/integration-points/content-editor)

and this link
[step by step to create ribbon button using powershell](https://sitecoresandbox.com/2016/06/03/content-editor-ribbon-buttons-using-sitecore-powershell-extensions/)